# select pushed back by a empty value in Vue.js

Tags: laravel, select, vue.js

It have some weird situation in the 2 related select,
sometime I choose the kind part select, the style select default text `--Choose--` will be pushed back by a empty value, how to resolve this problem?

Here is my html code :

```
<div id="app">
        <select v-model='kindVal' v-on:change="getStyle()">
            <option value="">--Choose--</option>
            <option v-for="kind in obj_kind" value="@{{ kind.code }}"> @{{ kind.name }} </option>
        </select>

        <select v-model='styleVal'>
            <option value="">--Choose--</option>
            <option v-for="style in obj_style" value="@{{ style.code }}"> @{{ style.name }} </option>
        </select>
</div>
```

And here is my app.js

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    kindVal : '',
    styleVal : '',

    obj_style :'',
    obj_kind : '',
  },
  ready: function(){
    this.getKind();
  },
  methods: {
    getKind: function(){
      $.getJSON('getParam',{ type : 'herald_kind' }, function(data) {
          this.obj_kind = data;
      }.bind(this));
    },
    getStyle:function(){
      data = {type : 'herald_style',ref : this.kindVal };

      $.getJSON('getParam',data, function(data) {
          this.obj_style = data;
      }.bind(this));
    },

  }
});
```

Comment: please provide jsfiddle

Comment: Instead of `v-on:change`, `$watch` the `kindVal` variable for changes.